# Perforce shelving a .strings file changes encoding

Tags: ios, localization, perforce, p4v, xcode9.2

I am creating a .strings from a .nib file. That is I'm changing the .nib file to a localized string file on Xcode 9.2.

Now I'm getting the .strings file with all the strings as required and the layout according to the base .xib file.

The problem arises when I check out the strings file and shelve it. The shelved file now suddenly is in Chinese. I can read it properly when I put it in some editor and change the encoding to Chinese(CP936 GBK).

But when I run the code, the strings appear perfectly as they were supposed to in all languages. Is there a way to submit the file to perforce without getting this weirdly encoded file?

Answer (score 1):

I think Perforce is mis-detecting the "filetype" of your file.

- If you're using P4V, right-click the file > Change Filetype. What's the "Base Filetype"?
- If you're using the cmdline client, run `p4 fstat FILENAME`. What's the "type"?

Probably all you have to do is change the filetype to the correct value.

Read more about this at https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4guide/appendix.filetypes.html.

Comment: Both before and after it remains the same "utf-16"

Comment: And was it generated as a UTF-16 file (before you added it to P4)? Or has Perforce mis-detected that?

Comment: You can set it to "binary" so that perforce doesn't try to process or change it.